# Pandas Iterrows Row Number & Percentage

Tags: python, pandas

I'm iterating over a dataframe with 1000s of rows. I ideally would like to know the progress of my loops - i.e. how many rows has it completed, what percentage of total rows has it completed etc.

Is there a way I can print the row number or even better, the percentage of rows iterated over?

My code it currently below. Currently, printing how it looks below right now displays some kind of tuple/list however all I need is the row number. This is probably simple.

```
for row in testDF.iterrows():

        print("Currently on row: "+str(row))
```

Ideal printed response:

```
Currently on row 1; Currently iterated 1% of rows
Currently on row 2; Currently iterated 2% of rows
Currently on row 3; Currently iterated 3% of rows
Currently on row 4; Currently iterated 4% of rows
Currently on row 5; Currently iterated 5% of rows
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop to begin with? there's most probably a better way. If you must, then the progress can be easily calculated using `enumerate` which returns the current row's index (along with the row itself) which can be divided by the total number of rows. `for index, row in enumerate(testDF.iterrows()): ... progress = index / len(testDF)`

Comment: I'm using the iterrows loop because I am create a new column with geocoded data. Most of the services which allow you to geocode have a limit, so I am also adding a delay of 0.1 seconds in my loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution with `format` if unique monotonic index (`0,1,2,...`):

```
for i, row in testDF.iterrows():
        print("Currently on row: {}; Currently iterrated {}% of rows".format(i, (i + 1)/len(testDF.index) * 100))
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(1332)
testDF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)))
print (testDF)
   0  1  2
0  8  1  9
1  4  3  5
2  0  1  3
3  1  8  6
4  7  4  7
5  7  5  3
6  7  9  9
7  0  1  2
8  1  3  4
9  0  0  3

for i, row in testDF.iterrows():
        print("Currently on row: {}; Currently iterrated {}% of rows".format(i, (i + 1)/len(testDF.index) * 100))
Currently on row: 0; Currently iterrated 10.0% of rows
Currently on row: 1; Currently iterrated 20.0% of rows
Currently on row: 2; Currently iterrated 30.0% of rows
Currently on row: 3; Currently iterrated 40.0% of rows
Currently on row: 4; Currently iterrated 50.0% of rows
Currently on row: 5; Currently iterrated 60.0% of rows
Currently on row: 6; Currently iterrated 70.0% of rows
Currently on row: 7; Currently iterrated 80.0% of rows
Currently on row: 8; Currently iterrated 90.0% of rows
Currently on row: 9; Currently iterrated 100.0% of rows
```

EDIT:

If some custom index values, solution with `zip` and [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) by `length of index` what is same of `length of df`:

```
np.random.seed(1332)
testDF = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)), index=[2,4,5,6,7,8,2,1,3,5])
print (testDF)
   0  1  2
2  8  1  9
4  4  3  5
5  0  1  3
6  1  8  6
7  7  4  7
8  7  5  3
2  7  9  9
1  0  1  2
3  1  3  4
5  0  0  3

for i, (idx, row) in zip(np.arange(len(testDF.index)), testDF.iterrows()):
    print("Currently on row: {}; Currently iterrated {}% of rows".format(idx, (i + 1)/len(testDF.index) * 100))

Currently on row: 2; Currently iterrated 10.0% of rows
Currently on row: 4; Currently iterrated 20.0% of rows
Currently on row: 5; Currently iterrated 30.0% of rows
Currently on row: 6; Currently iterrated 40.0% of rows
Currently on row: 7; Currently iterrated 50.0% of rows
Currently on row: 8; Currently iterrated 60.0% of rows
Currently on row: 2; Currently iterrated 70.0% of rows
Currently on row: 1; Currently iterrated 80.0% of rows
Currently on row: 3; Currently iterrated 90.0% of rows
Currently on row: 5; Currently iterrated 100.0% of rows
```

Comment: is it better to print the way you did or like follows ? `print('currently at row',i,'. iterated through ',100 * i / testDF.shape[0],'%')` and why ? thanks for your answer

Comment: @RayhaneMama -  I think there is many possible ways, your works also. I prefer `len(df.index)` because fastest way.

Comment: Note that here `i` is the index of each row. It works if the index contains integers from 0 to `len(df)-1`, but doesn't if `testDF` uses custom index values.

Comment: @AdrienMatissart - you are right, it is more complicated, I add solution.

Answer (score 11):

First of all `iterrows` gives tuples of `(index, row)`. So the proper code is

```
for index, row in testDF.iterrows():
```

Index in general case is not a number of row, it is some identifier (this is the power of pandas, but it makes some confusions as it behaves not as ordinary `list` in python where the index is the number of row). That is why we need to calculate the number of rows independently. We can introduce `line_number = 0` and increase it in each circle `line_number += 1`. But python gives us a ready tool for that: `enumerate`, which returns tuples of `(line_number, value)` instead of just `value`. So we come down to that code

```
for line_number, (index, row) in enumerate(testDF.iterrows()):
    print("Currently on row: {}; Currently iterated {}% of rows".format(
          line_number, 100*(line_number + 1)/len(testDF)))
```

P.S. python2 returns integer when you divide integers, that is why 999/1000 == 0, what you don't expect. So you can either force float or take `100*` to the beginning to get integer percent.

Answer (score 2):

for big dataframes, It's probably better to limit printing, wich is a time consuming task. Here is a way to do that :

```
dftest=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10**5,5))

percent=0
n=len(dftest)//100

for i,row in dftest.iterrows():
    if (i+1)//n>percent :
        percent +=1
        print (percent, "% realized")
    dftest.iloc[i] = 2*row #a job
```